Should I upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 and should I use the terminal to perform the upgrade?
I've been using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64-bit for a few years. I've been thinking of upgrading it to the newest version. I have the ISO file.
I've also been wondering about using terminal do perform the upgrade, but I have a slow DSL internet connection. I can get 5G by using my phone as a hotspot, but I don't know if that's practical for this. I'm looking for any advice and tips on upgrading.
I use Timeshift to back up my home folder. My system is working well, and I'm debating whether to upgrade at all, though I suspect the newer system has advantages.


You mention 64-bit as if significant; 64-bit is available for all architectures but only one architecture has 32 & 64 bit ISO so you're using ARM64?  (32-bit armhf is available).  You also don't mention if server or desktop (at least one different option exists for desktop installs but you only specify release; non-destructive re-install from ISO)

Added screenshot of PC specs if that helps.

If you have the ISO file of the latest LTS (24.04), then flash it to a USB drive and fresh install it in the partition where Ubuntu was installed. Terminal is not necessary in this process. This method is faster than upgrading and will cause less issues. If you have data in that partition, don't forget to take a backup

I am voting to close this question as it does not have a specific question but is asking for opinions about upgrading

@ArchismanPanigrahi The problem is that Jody has a slow internet connection and she has to deal with that problem too in addition to any other possibly opinion-based considerations.

If I install from an ISO as you say (I do have it) is my Timeshift backup or a backup of my Home folder all I need?

A non-destructive re-install (where used to install a newer version) requires internet to download the packages you had installed that aren't found on the ISO; so internet is a requirement if you're using additional apps. A destructive or clean install won't need internet, but won't (in most cases) be capable of running deb packages that were from the older release (if restored from backup for example - this could break your system!). If you're apps are snap, appimage, or flatpak that may differ, but results are package (not release) specific.

Non-destructive re-installs of Ubuntu Desktop are more limited (forced format for 24.04 & 24.10) on recent releases, except if using a flavor that uses calamares (where format isn't forced). Results however are package (or really app & app type) specific

For the graphical dialog, go to software and updates, click updates, and select what type of version you want to be notified for (LTS or all). Then open software updater; it should tell you a new version is available. Click install and follow prompts. If that doesn't work, open terminal and type sudo do-release-upgrade --frontend=DistUpgradeViewGtk3.
If you prefer upgrading in the command line, running sudo-do-release-upgrade should work just fine.
I would avoid using a hotspot for upgrading as you generally have limited data and it's not that fast, but if it's faster than your regular connection, go for it. You could try booting from the iso and seeing if it lets you upgrade instead of reinstall, but I haven't tested that recently. Make sure to back up your data, as stopping the installation in the middle WILL corrupt your hard drive!

You don't need to upgrade your Ubuntu 20.04 until April, 2030. Ubuntu 20.04 Extended Security Maintenance support will extend Ubuntu 20.04 support until April, 2030. Extended Security Maintenance and Ubuntu Pro are free for personal use on up to 5 machines (limitations apply). All you need is an Ubuntu One account. Extra security patching for Ubuntu LTS releases is now included in Ubuntu Pro.
